# Directory Watch Class (.net)

Tags: .net

I need a quick yes/no answer on this...

Is it possible to get a Directory Watch Class to watch a directory and its sub directories (all the way down) or does the Directory Watch Class only monitor changes/events in the parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. The property IncludeSubDirectories lets you do that.
You do mean the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Thanks Stefan! This may seem like a trivial question, but this is exactly why stackoverflow was created, now the question is in the kb, so other developers can benefit from it.

Comment: Just a question, you did mean the FileSystemWatcher not Directory watch class because I dont know about that class?

Comment: possible FileSystemWatcher is a newer name for the DirectoryWatchClass